# Как вывести значение из столбца другой таблицы, при нескольких одинаковых FK

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, мне тяжело коротко сформулировать заголовок, поэтому опишу свою проблему. 
Есть таблица - матч с полями (MatchID, LigueID(FK), FirstTeamID(FK), SecondTeamID(FK), Location, WinnerTeamID, firstTeamScope, SecondTeamScope), Как видите FirstTeamID(FK), SecondTeamID(FK) - это 2 ключа, которые ссылаются на одну и ту же таблицу и мне нужно вывести в представление не ID, а названия команды (таблица Teams (TeamID, TeamName)).

Я пробовал такой запрос:

```
select
  LigueName as 'Лига', 
  (select
    TeamName
  from Teams, Matches
   where (Teams.TeamID = Matches.FirstTeamID)) as 'Первая команда',
  (select
    TeamName
  from Teams, Matches
  where (Teams.TeamID = Matches.FirstTeamID)) as 'Вторая команда',
  (select
    TeamName
  from Teams, Matches
    where (Teams.TeamID = Matches.WinnerTeamID)) as 'Победитель',
  FirstTeamScope as 'Счет первой команды',
  SecondTeamScope as 'Счет второй команды'
from Matches, Teams, Ligues
where ((Matches.FirstTeamID = Teams.TeamID)
  and (Matches.SecondTeamID =    Teams.TeamID)
  and (Matches.LigueID = Ligues.LigueID))
```

Но понял свою ошибку, она в том, что 2 вложенных `select` возвращают просто все команды, а мне нужно именно получить 1 команду (1-ую для первого `select` и вторую для второго).

Возможно ли сделать по моей задумке или же у меня ошибка при конструировании бд? Я не думаю что тут связь М к М, т.к. у меня всегда только 2 команды, не больше не меньше.

Пример исходных данных

Таблица `Matches`

```
{
  Запись1: MatchID = 1, FirstTeamID = 1, SecondTeamID = 3, WinnerID = 3, FirstTeamScope = 15, SecondTeamScope = 20
  Запись2: MatchID = 2, FirstTeamID = 2, SecondTeamID = 3, WinnerID = 2, FirstTeamScope = 25, SecondTeamScope = 20
}
```

Таблица Teams

```
{
  Запись1: TeamID = 1, teamName = Spurs
  Запись2: TeamID = 2, teamName = Lakers
  Запись3: TeamID = 3, teamName = Ch. Bulls
}
```

После запроса нужно получить (лигу опускаю)

```
Запись1: Spurs   Ch.Bulls   Ch.Bulls   15   20
Запись2: Lakers  Ch.Bulls   Lakers     25   20
```

Т.е. как видите вместо ID команд указаны их названия

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример исходных данных и результат того что Вы хотите получить

Comment: обновил ответ, проверте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  l.LigueName,
  FirstCommand.TeamName,
  SecondCommand.TeamName,
  WinnerTeam.TeamName,
  m.FirstTeamScope,
  m.SecondTeamScope
from matches m
left join ligues l
  on m.LigueId = l.LigueId
left join teams FirstCommand
  on m.FirstTeamId = FirstCommand.TeamId
left join teams SecondCommand
  on m.SecondTeamId = SecondCommand.TeamId
left join teams WinnerCommand
  on m.WinnerTeamId=WinnerCommand.TeamId
```

---

что мы делаем: мы выбираем из главной таблицы необходимы нам записи, к главной таблице при помощи левых соединений подключаем таблицу команд нужное количество раз, в Вашем случае надо подключить таблицу `Team` 3 раза(1 команда, 2 команда, победитель)

Comment: У меня после From идет выражение where, мне left join делать после where или после From

Comment: @simplygood в соответствии с синтаксисом языка `join`ы должны быть до условия `where`

Comment: Ох у меня возникают проблемы с конструированием запроса, помогите пожалуйста, 
 `select LigueName as 'Лига', 
 
 FirstTeamScope as 'Счет первой команды',
 SecondTeamScope as 'Счет второй команды',
 Teams.TeamName as 'Название команды' 
from Ligues, Matches
matches left join Teams t1 on matches.FirstTeamID = Teams.TeamID
where ((Matches.FirstTeamID = Teams.TeamID) and (Matches.SecondTeamID = Teams.TeamID) and (Matches.LigueID = Ligues.LigueID)) ` 
Но возникает куча ошибок, помогите пожалуйста построить этот запрос грамотно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь! Мне надоело тупить и я прочел про join'ы, теперь я понимаю что пишу!